# invalid_parameter_exception on Moodle Rest API

Tags: rest, moodle

I am developing a web application that is connected to Moodle. I already set up the required functions needed to enable the web service. I already generated a token and when it comes to creating users, the response is always `invalid_parameter_exception` even I followed all the required parameters. I'm using POSTMAN to call the web service. Please see the parameters below:

`Method: POST`
`URL: https://moodle.testweb.online/webservice/rest/server.php`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of the parameters is incorrect. At a guess, the password doesn't look like it follows the default Moodle password requirements of containing at least 1 each of: number, uppercase letter, lowercase letter, special character.

You should also make sure that debugging is enabled for your site and display debug messages is on, as that should give you a lot more information when a webservice error occurs: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging